# Order of operators here

Tags: c++, operators

OK I need to expand code, but there's something very complex here:

```
((Traces.Last=new SymbolSequence::Node)->Prev=(Discard.First=Processing1)->Prev)->Next=Traces.Last;
```

I need to split those assignment to statements, but I can't figure the order of this.
The order with the parentheses are confusing me here, is it like math or the compiler do what he want?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find this "mother-of-all-ugly-assignments" mess of a statement?

Comment: This statement has undefined behavior(modifying `Traces.Last` and reading its value), so without knowing what it's *supposed* to do, there is no way to know how to correctly break it up.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Sure, but you can make a reasonable guess assuming the person who wrote the code didn't realize this was UB.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I can't tell XD, but all of the project is like this in a nutshell -_-.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Actually, that's what I try, to figure out but I can't even with debugging because it's just one line.

Comment: @user2468387: If all of the project is like this, you should ask the maintainer to rewrite it. Even better, don't. Let him comment everything and rewrite it yourself.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight For you:  `(Pattern0->Sequence.First->Prev->Next=Replacement0)->Prev=Pattern0->Sequence.First->Prev;` `while (Processing->Prev&&Processing2->Prev?!(Processing->Prev->Data!=Processing2->Prev->Data||Processing->Prev==Pattern0->Sequence.Last||Processing2->Prev==Discard.Last):0)` and there's more but I'll try to figure it out alone 0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your pain. Developers who code as if the whole world depended on one line of code should be smacked with a wet noodle in front of their girlfriends.

When refactoring code like that, it's always useful to start one piece at time. And test as you go.

Take a small expression that is in the innermost parenthesis group and refactor that out. Perhaps by assigning it to a variable. Every code is different so you do what you can. That will shrink that big line of code bit by bit.
Keep on doing that until you get the expression smaller and smaller. It also helps to put white space between the operators in order to physically see the grouping of the code and help glean the order of evaluation.

So given your original code:

```
((Traces.Last=new SymbolSequence::Node)->Prev=(Discard.First=Processing1)->Prev)->Next=Traces.Last;
```

split it out to this:

```
Traces.Last = new SymbolSequence::Node
((Traces.Last)->Prev = (Discard.First = Processing1)->Prev)->Next = Traces.Last;
```

Now work on another inner assignment:

```
Traces.Last = new SymbolSequence::Node
Discard.First = Processing1
((Traces.Last)->Prev = (Discard.First)->Prev)->Next = Traces.Last;
```

Then I work on the next innermost assignment

```
Traces.Last = new SymbolSequence::Node
Discard.First = Processing1
(Traces.Last)->Prev = (Discard.First)->Prev
( (Traces.Last)->Prev )->Next = Traces.Last;
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I tested it works, thanks! Now I can break this whole project o.o.

Comment: Glad to have helped. but I'm happier you tested it.

Answer (score 8):

The code is probably *intended* to be

```
Traces.Last = new SymbolSequence::Node;
Discard.First = Processing1;
Traces.Last->Prev = Discard.First->Prev;
Traces.Last->Prev->Next = Traces.Last;
```

However, due to the fact that it both accesses Traces.Last and sets it without an intervening sequence point, the actual result is undefined.  It is quite possible that a compiler might produce something like:

```
temp = Traces.Last;
Traces.Last = new SymbolSequence::Node;
Discard.First = Processing1;
Traces.Last->Prev = Discard.First->Prev;
Traces.Last->Prev->Next = temp;
```

and that the original programmer intended something like it.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the undefined behavior described in the comments, below is the AST representation according to `clang++`.  The AST shows the precedence of the operators as they were parsed.

I had to bootstrap your example with some types to satisfy `clang++`:

```
struct SymbolSequence
{
    struct Node
    {
        Node *First;
        Node *Last;
        Node *Prev;
        Node *Next;
    };
};

void foo()
{
    SymbolSequence::Node *Processing1;
    SymbolSequence::Node Traces;
    SymbolSequence::Node Discard;
    ((Traces.Last=new SymbolSequence::Node)->Prev=(Discard.First=Processing1)->Prev)->Next=Traces.Last;
}
```

AST:

```
void foo() (CompoundStmt 0x308b6e0 <go.cpp:14:1, line:19:1>
  (DeclStmt 0x3088dc8 <line:15:5, col:38>
    (0x3088d70 "SymbolSequence::Node *Processing1"))
  (DeclStmt 0x30891d8 <line:16:5, col:32>
    (0x3088e40 "SymbolSequence::Node Traces =
      (CXXConstructExpr 0x30891a8 <col:26> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node':'struct SymbolSequence::Node''void (void)')"))
  (DeclStmt 0x30892d8 <line:17:5, col:33>
    (0x3089250 "SymbolSequence::Node Discard =
      (CXXConstructExpr 0x30892a8 <col:26> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node':'struct SymbolSequence::Node''void (void)')"))
  (BinaryOperator 0x308b6b8 <line:18:5, col:99> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue '='
    (MemberExpr 0x308b618 <col:5, col:87> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue ->Next 0x3088b60
      (ImplicitCastExpr 0x308b600 <col:5, col:84> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' <LValueToRValue>
        (ParenExpr 0x308b5e0 <col:5, col:84> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue
          (BinaryOperator 0x308b5b8 <col:6, col:80> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue '='
            (MemberExpr 0x308b448 <col:6, col:46> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue ->Prev 0x3088b00
              (ImplicitCastExpr 0x308b430 <col:6, col:43> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' <LValueToRValue>
                (ParenExpr 0x308b410 <col:6, col:43> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue
                  (BinaryOperator 0x308b3e8 <col:7, col:39> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue '='
                    (MemberExpr 0x3089318 <col:7, col:14> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue .Last 0x3088aa0
                      (DeclRefExpr 0x30892f0 <col:7> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node':'struct SymbolSequence::Node' lvalue Var 0x3088e40 'Traces' 'struct SymbolSequence::Node':'struct SymbolSequence::Node'))
                    (CXXNewExpr 0x308b390 <col:19, col:39> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *'
                      (CXXConstructExpr 0x308b360 <col:23> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node':'struct SymbolSequence::Node''void (void)'))))))
            (ImplicitCastExpr 0x308b5a0 <col:51, col:80> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' <LValueToRValue>
              (MemberExpr 0x308b570 <col:51, col:80> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue ->Prev 0x3088b00
                (ImplicitCastExpr 0x308b558 <col:51, col:77> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' <LValueToRValue>
                  (ParenExpr 0x308b538 <col:51, col:77> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue
                    (BinaryOperator 0x308b510 <col:52, col:66> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue '='
                      (MemberExpr 0x308b4a0 <col:52, col:60> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue .First 0x3088a40
                        (DeclRefExpr 0x308b478 <col:52> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node':'struct SymbolSequence::Node' lvalue Var 0x3089250 'Discard' 'struct SymbolSequence::Node':'struct SymbolSequence::Node'))
                      (ImplicitCastExpr 0x308b4f8 <col:66> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' <LValueToRValue>
                        (DeclRefExpr 0x308b4d0 <col:66> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue Var 0x3088d70 'Processing1' 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *')))))))))))
    (ImplicitCastExpr 0x308b6a0 <col:92, col:99> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' <LValueToRValue>
      (MemberExpr 0x308b670 <col:92, col:99> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node *' lvalue .Last 0x3088aa0
        (DeclRefExpr 0x308b648 <col:92> 'struct SymbolSequence::Node':'struct SymbolSequence::Node' lvalue Var 0x3088e40 'Traces' 'struct SymbolSequence::Node':'struct SymbolSequence::Node')))))
```

Comment: Dude, I've been looking recently into using CLang to write my own static analyzers. I'd love to learn how you did that stuff.

Comment: Not rocket surgery.  `clang++ -cc1  -ast-dump example.cpp` ;)

Comment: That helps. Any more pointers you could give me? message me privately, I'd like to take this discussion offline.

Comment: @CJohnson, sorry, [no PMs on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/173950).  Look at my profile, my email address is there if you want to contact me.